# Entity Framework Lazy Loading Sum Child Table Slow

Tags: c#, sql, performance, entity-framework, linq

I am having performance issues with a sum method in entity framework. To explain this better, this is my table structure:

```
+----+--------+---------+-------+   +-----------+-----------+-------+
| Id |  Name  | Company | Color |   | ArticleId | Purchaser | Price |
+----+--------+---------+-------+   +-----------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | iPhone | Apple   | Black |   |         1 | Bob       |   350 |
|  2 | iPad   | Apple   | Grey  |   |         1 | Mat       |   220 |
+----+--------+---------+-------+   |         2 | Ivy       |   450 |
                                    +-----------+-----------+-------+
```

This is the related model for the Article table:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
...
[NotMapped]
public decimal? TotalAmount { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Purchase> PurchaserList { get; set; }
```

By making use of lazy loading, entity framework will autmatically load all the related purchasers. Then I simply sum the price for each article and set it equal to the TotalAmount property:

```
articleList = dbContext.Article.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 10).ToList();

foreach(var article in articleListe)
    article.TotalAmount= article.PurchaserList.Sum(x => x.Price);
```

However, this takes about 4 seconds for a table with just 100 entries. Of course, this is way too slow and I need to speed this up by quite a bit. Does anyone have any suggestions or anything that I can improve in order to make this faster?

**Edit:**

As mentioned by rad, changing it from lazy loading to eager loading improved the loading time from 4 seconds to 0.17 seconds. I removed the virtual keywork and changed my code like this:

```
articleList = dbContext.Article.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 10).Include(x => x.PurchaserList).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use eager loading (`Include`) instead of lazy loading.
Lazy loading is not a good choice in your scenario, because for each `PurchaserList` to be retrieved, a new connection is made to database (i.e. 100 connections in your example) and that's the database IO that is taking the time.
You can trace the queries and connections using Sql Profiler.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Now it only takes 170ms. So I am wondering is there any case that I would choose lazy loading over eager loading?

Comment: Yes, lazy loading and eager loading are both useful options, however, you need to be careful when to use them. I prefer to use lazy loading when there is only one or few related objects to be retrieved with the main object, but it's very dangerous to use lazy loading in loops.

Comment: Also, Lazy loading is preferred over eager loading when you don't need to retrieve all related data at once.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this to get your sum directly from db, using projections:

```
articleListSum = dbContext.Article.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 10).Select(x => x.PurchaserList.Select(y => y.Price)).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();
```

Comment: That would be the total of all purchases for all articles from the same company.  The OP wants the sum for each article.  Also for that to work you need a `SelectMany`.